# What's the name of this semi-serif font ("arif")?

Tags: font-identification

What is the name of this semi-serif font?

[image: Font]

(View edit history for image with finer detail (but awful colour combination)

Answer (score 1):

The font is close to [Alex Font](http://www.dafont.com/alex.font)

There are two versions of this font - the old and the new one, probably "f" comes from the old version.

[image]

[image]